# How to select column of dataframe using numbers

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

At the moment I am selecting columns the usual way:

```
`df$column1`
```

But I want to loop through the columns of my dataframe into a plot function, and when I use the method:

```
`df[,1]`
```

I get the error:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

So what would be the best way to select columns of the dataframe so that I can easily loop through the columns and avoid this error.

Comment: What does `df[[1]]` print? I believe this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: That works! simple as that. Thanks for the help much appreciated.

Comment: No problem; I'll write up an answer with more info

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Comment: You should study `help("$")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access dataframe columns using double square brackets e.g. `df[[1]]` prints the first column. For more info on why/how/etc, see Dave Tang's blog post: https://davetang.org/muse/2013/08/16/double-square-brackets-in-r